# Perl assign array to hash and vice-versa

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I would like to get your help to figure out how to add a long array to a hash key value, how to assign the key value to a temporay array from where the data will be manipulated, than assign the array (or what I have left) back to the same hash key.
A sample of what I am looking for is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;

use warnings FATAL => 'all';
```

**My set of arrays that will contain only integers**

```
my @Array1 = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '09', '10', '11', '12']; 
my @Array2 = ['05', '06', '07', '08', '03', '04', '09']; 
my @Array3 = ['09', '10', '11', '12', '02', '03', , '07', '08' ]; 
my @ArrayN = ['N', 'N', 'N', 'N'];
```

**My hash with keys identified by integers (Is it possible?)**

```
my %Hash;
```

**Assigning arrays to key values;**

```
%Hash{'1'} = @Array1 (or $Array1); 
%Hash{'2'} = @Array2 (or $Array2); 
%Hash{'3'} = @Array3 (or $Array3);
%Hash{'N'} = @ArrayN (or $ArrayN);
```

**Assign a hash key value to a temporary array**

```
my @TempArray = $Hash{'1'};
```

**Some process with the temporary array including:**

- (Delete the first element/item of the temporary array, let's say the
  numnber "01"');
- (Check if the array has a especifc value, let's say numbers 03 and
  09);
- (Delete especific values from the array, let's say the
  numnbers 03 and 09');
- (Check how many elements/items exist in the array);

**than assign the value back to the hash**

```
%Hash{'1'} = @TempArray;
```

I have found many posts that are not helping so much, as they don't talk about long arrays.

Comment: (1) Either `$array_reference = [ ... ]` or `@array = ( ... )` (2) A hash value is a scalar, so you need `$` in front and must assign a _reference_ of an array to it (which is a scalar). Thus: `$hash{'1'} = $array_reference` or `$hash{'1'} = \@array`, where \ takes a reference, here of an array  (3) De-reference that array reference to get an array `@TempArray = @{ $hash{'1'} }`.  Finally:  This site is not a good place to go to for getting basic tutorials and this kind of a question is blatantly off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

By using square brackets for your lists, you've actually created an array reference, which is a scalar. Your assignments should thus be:

```
my $Array1 = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '09', '10', '11', '12']; 
my $Array2 = ['05', '06', '07', '08', '03', '04', '09'];
```

etc.

Next, when assigning these references as hash keys, you must use the $ sigil since you're referring to the hash value (a scalar) and not the hash itself.

```
$Hash{'1'} = $Array1; 
$Hash{'2'} = $Array2;
```

Now if you want to assign these references to array variables, you must dereference them:

```
my @TempArray = @{ $Hash{'1'} };
```

As for your list of operations/checks on these arrays:

**Delete the first item:**

```
shift @TempArray;
```

**Check if a certain value is an element of the array:**

```
my $check = grep { $_ == $some_number } @TempArray;
```

(`$check` will be the number of matches returned, and thus will evaluate to false if you get zero matches);

**Delete an specific element (index unknown) from the array:**

Every occurrence of a certain value?

```
@TempArray = grep { $_ != $some_number } @TempArray;
```

A specific element (not necessarily first or last)? Need to know the offset.

```
splice @TempArray => $index;
```

**Check the length of the array:**

```
my $length = @TempArray;
```

(referring to an array in list context returns its length)

Comment: It seems the line below is getting the array size instead the array elements: (it is in the line 13: ` my @TempArray = @{ $Hash{'1'} };`  #Can't use string ("8") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at /bkp_local/MyCodes/chess/test.pl line 13.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, it would seem that you have the value of $Hash{'1'} as a string and not an array reference of strings. You may be missing square brackets somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> My set of arrays that will contain only integers

Actually, your arrays contain strings :-)

> ```
> my @Array1 = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
> ```

Here's your first serious error. Arrays are initialised from **lists** - so you need round brackets, `(...)`, not square brackets, `[...]`.

You wanted this:

```
my @Array1 = ('01', '02', '03', '04', '09', '10', '11', '12');
```

Alternatively, you could use your original square brackets. But they give you an array **reference**. A reference is a scalar value, so you store it in a scalar variable.

```
my $Array1_ref = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
```

> My hash with keys identified by integers (Is it possible?)

Well, the keys of a hash are always strings. But that's ok. Perl will seamlessly convert integers to strings. And it's not necessary here because you're actually using strings (`'1'`), not integers (`1`).

> ```
> %Hash{'1'} = @Array1;
> ```

A couple of errors here. The values in a hash are scalars. So you access them using a scalar sigil (`$`, not `%`). And, of course, an array isn't  a scalar so you can't store it in a hash value. You can, however, store an array **reference** in a hash value (as references are scalar values.

```
$Hash{'1'} = \@Array1; # use \ to get a reference
```

Alternatively, if you stuck with the `[...]` version and stored your array reference in `$Array_ref`, then you can do:

```
$Hash{'1'} = $Array_ref;
```

> Assign a hash key value to a temporary array

The value in your hash is a reference to your array. So you need to **dereference** it before storing it in an array variable.

```
@Temp_Array = @{ $Hash{'1'} };
```

> Delete the first element/item of the temporary array, let's say the numnber "01"'

```
shift @Temp_Array;
```

> Check if the array has a especifc value, let's say numbers 03 and 09

```
if (grep { $_ eq '03' } @Temp_Array) {
  say "03 is in the array";
}
```

> Delete especific values from the array, let's say the numnbers 03 and 09

```
@Temp_Array = grep { $_ ne '03' and $_ ne '09' } @Temp_Array;
```

> Check how many elements/items exist in the array

Simply evaluate the array in a scalar expression.

```
$num_of_elements = @Temp_Array;
```

> then assign the value back to the hash

Once again, you need to take a **reference** to the array.

```
$Hash{'1'} = \@Temp_Array
```

It's worth pointing out that you don't need to copy the array to a temporary array variable in order to manipulate it. Anywhere that I have used `@Temp_Array` in the examples above, you can replace it with `@{ $Hash{'1'} }` and you will be manipulating the array inside the hash directly.

```
shift @{ $Hash{'1'} }; # for example
```

> I have found many posts that are not helping so much, as they don't talk about long arrays.

That's probably because long arrays and short arrays (and middle-sized arrays) are all handled in exactly the same way in Perl.